# How can we use power app button in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to use power app button in power Bi desktop but couldn't find the option.

Can you please help how to achive this feature ?

I can able to use power BI button integration with power automation.

Thanks,
Brahma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the button for Power Apps. If you don't see it, please update Power BI Desktop.

[image]